# two parameter settings of using fread

Tags: r

I once saw the following line of code of using fread this way

```
c1<-fread('C:\\desktop\\traindata.csv',skip=4,head=F)[1:15,1:3]
```

I have two questions, should it be `head` or `header`? What does the `[1:15,1:3]` mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally it should be `header` but since R does partial matching of argument `head` works here and so would `h = F`.

`[1:15,1:3]` is used for subsetting the data after reading. This means select rows 1 to 15 and column 1 to 3.